# SharedPReferences are not restored (restore the default value only)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have a new Activity called in this way:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
....
                    context.startActivity(i);
```

At this Activity i have to restore/save some preferences based on the WebView position and a Seekbar(webview textzoom) positions/number.

so i made this:

```
public class LerLeiActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    SharedPreferences preferences;

    WebView wv;
    SeekBar skbar;

    HideOptionsMenu hdMenu;



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.leituradalei);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        skbar = (SeekBar) this.findViewById(R.id.seekFont);
        hdMenu = new HideOptionsMenu(this, wv);
        hdMenu.setWebViewURL(intent.getExtras().getString("path"));
        hdMenu.setSeekBarDefault(skbar);

        hdMenu.restoreLastPreference("preferences");

    }
```

and this HideOptionsMenu have this methods:

```
WebView wv;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SeekBar skb;
public HideOptionsMenu(Context c, WebView webview) {
    this.context = c;
        this.wv = webview;

    }
    public void savePreferences(String leiID) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(leiID, 0);
        preferences.edit().putInt("fontZoom", skb.getProgress());
        preferences.edit().putInt("scrollY", wv.getScrollY());
        preferences.edit().commit();
        Log.d("shared", "saving");
        Log.d("shared", "fontZoom " + skb.getProgress());
        Log.d("shared", "scrollY " + wv.getScrollY());
    }
    public void restoreLastPreference(String leiID) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(leiID, 0);
        int lastZoom = preferences.getInt("fontZoom", 100);
        int lastY = preferences.getInt("scrollY", 0);

        Log.d("shared", "restoring");
        Log.d("shared", "fontZoom " + lastZoom);
        Log.d("shared", "scrollY " + lastY);
       // wv.getSettings().setTextZoom(lastZoom);
        //wv.setScrollY(lastY);

    }
```

i cant understand why it keep loading the default values of stored, since i have this in the Log.d

```
//loading
D/shared﹕ restoring
D/shared﹕ fontZoom 100
D/shared﹕ scrollY 0

//saving
D/shared﹕ saving
D/shared﹕ fontZoom 167
 D/shared﹕ scrollY 447

//after closing the Activity and opening it again
 D/shared﹕ restoring
D/shared﹕ fontZoom 100
D/shared﹕ scrollY 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `edit()` function only once, it returns an `Editor` object. So you should do the following:

```
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("fontZoom", skb.getProgress());
editor.putInt("scrollY", wv.getScrollY());
editor.commit();
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit()):

> returns a new instance of the SharedPreferences.Editor interface, allowing you to modify the values in this SharedPreferences object.

So everytime you call `edit()` you get a new instance of which you do not commit the changes.

Comment: owwww, it worked, thanks now i understand, thanks the answer, it worked perfectly =)!! 

just a little question, if a create in another activity, i can reentrive the shared preferences created by this one?

Comment: @user2582318 If you are in another activity, you should just get the SharedPreferences with the `getSharedPreferences(String, int)` method and use the same String as you use for the SharedPreferences in this class